# Android FileNotFoundException in uploading Photo

Tags: android

I have problem with finding photo after saving.
Here is how i am creating Intent to take photo from camera and save filePath to it.

```
private void takePhoto(int position)
{
    Meter meter = adapter.getItem(position);
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File tempFile = createTempFile(meter.id, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, storageDir);
    if(tempFile != null)
    {
        lastPhotoPath = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d(TAG, "temp picture path=" + lastPhotoPath);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(tempFile));
        try
        {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST);
            lastPhotoPosition = position;
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException exc)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "activity to take photo not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Then later i want to upload this image to server. 
Here is how i am doing this.

```
public void compose(OutputStream out) throws DataStorageException
{
    Log.d("MainMenuActivity", "file not found in path " + path);
    InputStream in = null;
    try
    {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));

        // TODO: there is a better way
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        while(true)
        {
            int length = in.read(buf);
            if(length < 0)
                break;
            out.write(buf, 0, length);
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException exc)
    {
        throw new DataStorageInternalErrorException("FileNotFoundException, FileRequestComposer compose");
    }
    catch(IOException exc)
    {
        // TODO: probably network error
        throw new DataStorageInternalErrorException("IOException, FileRequestComposer compose");
    }
    finally
    {
        if(in != null)
        {
            try
            {
                in.close();
            }
            catch(IOException exc)
            {
                // FIXME
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I check filePath from saving and filePath to save they both completely identical:

`temp picture path=/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/19520983731349.jpg`

`file not found in path /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/19520983731349.jpg`

And the exception is thrown in method `compose()`

`FileNotFoundException, FileRequestComposer compose`

Any ideas where i am doing wrong?

P.S. And i can't see this file in /mnt/sdcard/Pictures mb. he is lost or somethinf like this? Please suggest any ideas.

P.P.S Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vodomer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
              android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:name="com.vodomer.DatabaseApplication" >
        <activity android:name="Vodomer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.AddressesListActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MainMenuActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MetersActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.PersonalAccountActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share your manifest file here ?

Comment: Try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`, meanwhile give me a few minutes to test code

Comment: Try using this line instead : `File tempFile = new File(storageDir,  meter.id + JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX);` and see if you have picture stored after taking it.

Comment: @kiruwka. Yes, now i can see this file in my pictures folder.

Comment: @kiruwka wait. steel testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely with the way you create File. Instead of [createTempFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) try regular constructor :

```
File tempFile = new File(storageDir,  meter.id + JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX);
```

Generally, you also want to make sure that your `storageDir` folder exists and create it with [mkdirs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) if needed.

Comment: I don't now what's happened. But he saved my picture only one time.
Next time i was trying to use this didn't give me nothing.

Comment: @Anatol sounds weird. Try this : manually remove previously created pictures from `/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/`, reinstall your app with code above and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Add this path for storing image on sdcard.

```
final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
```